# (Done) Unsure why this is closed for the reason given, VTRO request

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

["Past Employer" Wants Source Code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122164/past-employer-wants-source-code)

Nothing particularly uncommon about dodgy people trying to get free work done or evading paying.

Comment: Third VTRO cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it was an absolutely insane close reason.